# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to convert SetupSerilog in .NET Core 5 to .NET Core 6 Program.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a code in ASP.NET Core-5 Web API which I want to convert to ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

I have this extension.

LogSettingsExtension:

```
public static class LogSettingsExtension
{
    public static void SetupSerilog(IConfiguration config)
    {
        DocumentStore ravenStore = new()
        {
            Urls = new string[] { config["RavenDBConfigurations:ConnectionURL"] },
            Database = config["RavenDBConfigurations:DatabaseName"]
        };

        ravenStore.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(config["RavenDBConfigurations:CertificateFilePath"],
            config["RavenDBConfigurations:Password"], X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        ravenStore.Initialize();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.File(
                path: ".\\Logs\\log-.txt",
                outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information
            )
            .WriteTo.RavenDB(ravenStore)
            .CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

In .NET Core-5 I used it in Program.cs as:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        var isDevelopment = env == Environments.Development;

        IConfiguration config = ConfigurationSetupExtension.GetConfig(isDevelopment);

        LogSettingsExtension.SetupSerilog(config);
        try
        {
            Log.Information("Application is starting...");
            CreateHostBuilder(args)
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex.StackTrace, "Application failed to start");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

}
```

How do I transform this to Program.cs in .NET Core-6 since everything has changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your Program.cs as shown below.
Initially a BootstrapLogger is setup that is used during Main method only and logs only on console. During CreateHostBuilder Serilog is setup from your configuration for use in your program.

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
         Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateBootstrapLogger();

        try
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
            return 1;
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) =>
         {
             configuration
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration);
         })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

Sample configuration in your appsettings.json that will log on console and file.

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": { "path": "logs\\log-file-.txt" }
  }
],  
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
```

}

One issue is that this provides no direct way to log in your Startup -> ConfigureServices(). There are some workarounds however.